# Using a socket instantiated from main activity in another activity

Tags: java, android, sockets

I created socket in main activity

```
public class MainActivity...{
..

public void sendToServer(String msg){
out.println("start");
}
..
socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVER_PORT); //Socket Creation
out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket
                            .getOutputStream())), true); //stream to kick  data to server
}
```

If I call sendToServer("hi") on Button click from main Activity, I can see msg in server side. I was trying to call it from another activity somehow like

```
MainActivity con = new MainActivity();
con.sendToServer("hii");
```

Confused! how do I make it happen? -_-

Comment: You could store the reference to the socket in a static class that is accessible by both activities.

Comment: One cannot create activities with new to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write some thing like this . To create singleton class.

```
public class SocketClient {

    private static SocketClient sClient;

    private SocketClient() {

    }

    public synchronized static SocketClient getInstance() {
        if (sClient == null) {
            sClient = new SocketClient();
        }
        return sClient;
    }

    public void connect() {
        //Your connection code will come here
    }

    public void disconnect() {
        //Your disconnection code will come here
    }

    public void sendMessage(String message) {
        // message sending will code 
    }

}
```

You can access it anywhere in the application.

Answer (score 0):

@Krish's approach is a good one, but I think some more explanation is needed:

From an object oriented view: You should move that Socket *implementation* to a  separate type, because the Activity *must not know* about it; make your own interface and name it based on it's purpose (e.g. 'SaySomethingService'). That way you can test your Activity better (you don't need to create Sockets during a Unit test, which is nice), and you can change your implementation, without having to change your Activity (wich is nice, too).

(Other than that: I dislike the Singleton Pattern, some even argue, it's an antipattern. And there are more elegant solutions - but that depends on the requirements, the size, etc; in the end, it depends on the dev's who write and maintain the app.)